# Web USB API not working properly when calling USB device microphone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webusb

I'm trying to trigger Microphone using Web USB API on Chrome, the below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index.html</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/webusb.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="btn">CLick me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my js file:

```
  $(function() {
      console.log("ready!");
      $("#btn").click(function()
      {
          myFunction();
      });   
  });

  function myFunction()
  {

    let device;
    try 
    {
        device = navigator.usb.requestDevice
        ({ filters: [{vendorId: 0x0451, providerId:0x2036}]});
        console.log('Clicked');
        navigator.usb.getDevices()
        .then(devices => {
            console.log("devices: " + devices);
    });
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        debugger;
        console.log(error.message); 
    };
    if (device !== undefined) {
    }
}
```

I found the providerId and vendorId from Device Manager:
[image: providerId & vendorId]
I was expecting a microphone permission allowance pop-up window but only get the below result, which shows No Compatible devices found. So how to achieve it?
[image: result]

Comment: The device you're showing is a USB hub, not a microphone.  In any case, why not use the Media Device API instead?  That's a much better abstraction if you're trying to record audio.

Comment: Sure, I will take a look. I tried to find vendorID and providerID in Device Manager under Audio inputs and outputs category, but only found "MMDEVAPI\AudioEndpoints", I observed that if I plugged in my mic, then this USB hub showed up and once unplugged, then it disappeared, so I was assuming it could work.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, Media Device API works!